How SwiftUI create view's tree?
I stack with problem of @Environmentobject and NavigationLink. I searched in the internet about swiftUI environment and what is it and how SwiftUI build views tree but nothing special.
What I see, if we have something this:
struct TempView: View {
      var body: some View {
          Text("Hello, World!")
      }
 }

and
struct TempApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TempView()
        }
    }
}

we have tree with one way TempView --> Text
but what if we have Navigation?
struct TempView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                TempView2()
            } label: {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct TempView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            TempView3()
        } label: {
            Text("World")
        }
    }
}

struct TempView3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("End")
    }
}

the views tree will be next:

TempApp --> NavigationStack
NavigationStack --> TempView
NavigationStack --> TempView2
NavigationStack --> TempView3

is it right?
What is a problem. Problem is that if i create a StateObject in TempView and pass in like environmentobject view modifier to TempView2 , then TmepView3 will not see it.
This code crash:
class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "test text"
}

struct TempView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                TempView2()
                    .environmentObject(viewModel)
            } label: {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct TempView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            TempView3()
        } label: {
            Text("World")
        }
    }
}
    
struct TempView3: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.text)
    }
}


Navigation links are siblings and the environment has to be injected at the uppermost shared view which is the stack. This is expected behavior according to Apple.

The link also has a link to Apple’s response on the subject.

uppermost shared view is TempView2() and not NavigationStack. If i have more view in this hierarchy i do not want to share across all, so " uppermost shared view " is not clear what is uppermost shared view and how swiftUI declare it

@loremipsum I readed your answer, and generally including comments I am right. TempView and TempView2 are on in same branch of views tree

It every navigation link destination is its own branch that stems from the stack. They don’t share environments, they don’t spawn from another link

thats the answer for all problem. I did not find it in you answer on provided question. Not mine. But never mind. You can add this to your answer.

I give my bad egg carton analogy there. Each navigation link is an egg and all eggs are in a carton (NavigationStack) the only thing that connects the eggs is the carton
